# How did Earth's poison plants come to the Predators' hunting planet?

Tags: plot-explanation, predators

In *Predators* (2010) when the humans landed on the alien planet, Edwin finds a poisonous plant that grows on Earth. He even knows the scientific name for that, he told it to the others but they didn't listen.

How did these Earth poison plants come to the alien planet?

Did the Predators add them to their hunting planet to get a more interesting hunt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This is never explained

The implication though is that the Predators have been in contact with Earth for **millions** of years.

There is a comment in the <del>[script](http://www.joblo.com/scripts/predators.pdf)</del>:

> ```
> They have been extinct since the early Cretaceous period. 
> 125 million years ago.
> ```

Humans *[**did not exist**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_evolution) 125 million years ago* so it's unlikely that the transportation of plants then would have been related to hunting them.

It's possible that the plants were transplanted to make the hunting of *other* creatures more interesting but there is nothing written about that.

Comment: On the basis that they've been coming for millions of years, I'd suggest that a few of the Predators had stepped on the plants on Earth, and then potentially spread the seeds on the hunting planet without even meaning to - simple transfer could do it.  If the soil is fertile for the poisonous plants, that would let them grow?

Comment: That would be the logical conclusion but there's no evidence either way.

Comment: Natural evolution of plant species over huge time periods could also potentially explain it. Habitable and fertile ground and a sane atmospheric gas content ( as seen by vegetation thriving and humans being able to breathe ) it would not be beyond the realms of fantasy to envisage that plant species had naturally just evolved and grew of its own accord.